# Можно ли использовать git в консоли Node.js ? Если да, то как установить?

Tags: windows, node.js, git

Можно ли установить так

```
npm install nodegit
```

и потом просто писать команды git в консоли Node.js ? Использовать одну консоль для git и gulp мне удобнее будет..

Comment: А какой результат, если выполнить `npm install nodegit`?

Comment: Под консолью node.js вы имеете в виду [REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL)?